# Is this phrase correct? "Got it, thanks!"

Tags: american-english, british-english

I received this regularly from my colleagues but not sure if this is grammatically correct

Comment: What are your doubts?  It's not a complete sentence, but people often don't speak or write entirely in complete sentences.

Comment: Define "grammatically correct". It's a perfectly natural usage, which you could understand to be a "reduced" form of something like *I have **got it**, for which I convey my **thanks** to you,* but of course we don't often use such verbose phrasing.

Comment: It is the way everyone says it. It's not something Jane Austen would write, or what a copy editor would accept for a news article, but it is exactly how one of many ways there are to say 'I understand"  to another person.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's grammatically *correct* in informal language. 
Strictly speaking, it's not grammatical (it should be I've got it in active or I got it in passive), but it's well established among native speakers and only prescriptivists might claim it shouldn't be used. As far as the rest of the world and linguistic usus is concerned, there's nothing wrong with this sentence in an informal setting.

It's fine to write it to your colleagues, but might not be fine to write it to your supervisor or boss, depends on the company and whether it's American English or European English (EuEn tends to be more formal).